# Derivatives exam question

Tags: derivatives

I posted a thread yesterday : [Quadratic formula - math error](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631939/quadratic-formula-math-error)

I've finally got an understand to it and can work out maximum/minimum ect but for the exam questions we're expected to give an answer like this : [image]

I've no idea what this means, if anyone could help me out in the most basic mathematic way possible. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The table simply means (from left to right):

- When $x$ tends towards $-\infty$, $f(x)$ will tend towards $+\infty$
- When $x$ is less than $9$, $f(x)$ will decrease
- When $x = 9$, $f(x)$ has the value $0$, which is a local minimum of $f$
- When $x$ is greater than $9$, $f(x)$ will increase
- When $x$ tends towards $+\infty$, $f(x)$ will tend towards $+\infty$

Comment: hey are you online?

Answer (score 0):

First of all $f$ must be a real valued function. In order to find min/max you need to study the graph of $f$ and see where it is monotone (increasing, decreasing).
In order to do that usually you find the sign of the $f'$ and its roots. The roots of $f'$ are possible min/max of $f$. So you find the roots and draw a small table with rows $x, f(x),f'(x)$ and you mark the roots of $f'$ and the values of $x$ for which $f$ or $f'$ are not well defined.
You put a + (-) sign where $f'$ is positive and this is where f is increasing (decreasing).
If at a root of $f'$ there is a change of sign then you have a min/max. 
The arrows in the table mean decreasing and increasing respectively. 
You need to read some simple textbook describing how to find min/max in the way you want